Add marker to Mapbox in Java Android
I saw a tutorial on Youtube, there is a step that they use "AnnotationPluginImplKt" and "PointAnnotationManagerKt". After add  implementation 'com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.17.1' to build.gradle, I can import PointAnnotationManagerKt but AnnotationPluginImplKt is still not available. Anyone can tell me where I can import that or any other way to add marker to Mapbox in Java Android, thank you!
I have create PointAnnotationOptions but I don't know how to add it to my Mapbox
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.pointmap);
PointAnnotationOptions marker = new PointAnnotationOptions()
                .withPoint(Point.fromLngLat(106.7,10.8))
                .withIconImage(image);


This is described well in the documentation however it is in Kotlin.
What you should do in Java is:

Create an instance of Annotation API.
Create an instance of PointAnnotationManager and pass your mapView object.
After that you need to create PointAnnotationOptions object and define your coordinate and set up an icon of your choice.
And in the end you need to call pointAnnotationManager and create a marker by using create() method and passing your custom pointAnnotationOptions as an argument.

That's it. It would be helpful, if you share a code where your did this 4 points above. Please check it and if it does not work, please let me know.

Thank you, I've given up on new version, I tried old version of Mapbox and it worked well.
I used this code with this version 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.5.0'
'''
public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
map = mapboxMap;
map.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS);
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(10.8,106.7)).zoom(12.0).build();
map.setCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().setPosition(new LatLng(10.8,106.7)));
}
'''
